# Object users in Observable Angular 8

Tags: json, angular, typescript, rxjs

I created a service and I try call API method (HTTP GET) and I put my data in Observable, I don't understand why I don't see all data(object) from API GET.

`angular-component.ts`

```
public allUsers$: Observable<User[]>;
constructor(private usersService: UsersService) { }
ngOnInit() {
   this.allUsers$ = this.getAllUsers();
   console.log(this.allUsers$) 
}
private getAllUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
   return this.usersService.getUsers(); 
}
```

In console I have this message:

[image]

`users.service.ts`

```
public getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
  return this.apiService.get(this.type) as Observable<User[]>;
}
```

`api.service.ts`

```
public get(url: string): Observable<any> {
   return this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + `/${url}`);
}
```

`nodejs-route.js`

```
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const getAllUsers = await User.find().populate("orders.order_id");
  res.status(200).send(getAllUsers);
});
```

Comment: You need to subscribe to get the values out of the Observable, or have a .toPromise() on the end of your call

Comment: I'd recommend running through https://angular.io/guide/http, which explains this.

Comment: If I put subscribe on getUsers() I have an error, like: Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<User[]>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.

Comment: what type is your http field ? in api.service.ts

Comment: The type field is an object

Answer (score 0):

Always keep in mind that an Observable does nothing.

As the lead RxJS developer, Ben Lesh, once said:

> Observables themselves are enert. They don't stream anything or do
>   anything. They are templates for streaming/actions/observations that
>   will be set up on a subscription.

And there are two basic ways to subscribe:

1. With an async pipe.
2. Using the `subscribe` method.

The async pipe in a template AUTOMATICALLY subscribes and unsubscribes for you.

So in your **template**, you'd have something like this:

```
<div class="card"
     *ngIf="allUsers$ | async as users">
```

Then you will be able to access `users` in your template, such as in an `*ngFor`.

However, using an async pipe makes it a bit more difficult to access the data in your component code. So you can NOT just do this to see your data:

```
console.log(this.allUsers$)
```

All that will give you is information on the Observable, as you saw.

---

The other option is to subscribe in your component:

```
sub: Subscription
users: User[]

ngOnInit() {
   this.sub = this.getAllUsers().subscribe(
    users => {
       this.users = users;
       console.log(users);
    );
}
```

The `subscribe()` method returns a Subscription that you can then use to manually unsubscribe.

You will then have an array of users `User[]`, NOT an `Observable<User[]>` as your component property. Your template can then bind to this array.

The first technique (async pipe) is normally the recommended approach.

Comment: thanks for help, I have an error like, 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'

Comment: If you have the code as above, then this.getAllUsers is not of type `void`. Consider posting a simple stackblitz that clearly demonstrates your issue. Otherwise it's hard to tell what your issue may be. And as others have said ... consider spending some time reading and understanding how Observables work.